# Показ начала блока кода, поиск аналогов

Tags: c#, ide, плагин, visual-studio

Подскажите, пожалуйста, бесплатный плагин или IDE с функцией, которая может показать в конце блока фигурных скобок, подсказку о том, какой конкретно блок кода завершается, особенно актуально когда много условий или сама функция объемная, сложная и нет возможности её раздробить.

Вот пример для студии, плагин VSCommands, может кто видел бесплатные аналоги такой фичи?
[image]

Comment: Извиняюсь, что игнорирую вопрос, но здесь скорее стоит задуматься о рефакторинге кода, а не о том, как бы поудобнее с ним ужиться. Дублирование кода не есть хорошо.

Comment: Использую решарпер и для подобного в том числе. 
Предыдущий комент - первое, что приходит в голову.

Comment: @Shad я специально подчеркнул в вопросе, что функция (или блок кода) сложная, можете считать, что она уже разбита на более простые. Или у Вас все блоки кода видны целиком на экране? Я использую крупный шрифт потому, что бережно отношусь к своему зрению (от среднего и мелкого шрифта глаза быстро устают), поэтому часто приходится скроллить, чтобы увидеть какая фигурная скобка закрывает какой код блока, это отнимает моё время и очень надоедает.А такая возможность редактора бы мне очень помогла.

Comment: Emacs легко "прыгает" по скобкам.

Comment: @Merlin, в этом фрагменте кода решарпер подчеркнёт Вам 3 оператора continue c пометкой "Redundant code" и будет совершенно прав. К тому же "сложный" - понятие довольно относительное ;)

Comment: Этот фрагмент кода всего лишь пример, демонстрирующий то, что я хочу найти, можете включить воображение и представить несколько блоков кода не вмещающихся на экран полностью. Сложность в данном случае - сложность восприятия (видишь конец блока, но затрудняешься определить какого именно), такое бывает когда много условных переходов и не только. Вы мне уже второй раз говорите про рефакторинг, хотя я Вам уже ответил, можете считать, что функции разбиты на более простые и это касается не данного фрагмента, который является примером работы плагина, а не примером "сложного" кода.

Comment: Ну @avp уже назвал emacs. Могу добавить, что у vim'а тоже проблем нет ни с показом парных скобок, ни с фолдингом (сворачиванием в одну строку) блоков

Comment: @avp просто посмотреть и прыгнуть, чтобы посмотреть для меня большая разница, но все равно спасибо, буду знать.

Comment: @Merlin, если уж такой разговор, то я в подобной ситуации использую 2 фрейма (окна X-window). В одном смотрю-редактирую, в окнах (их в фрейме может быть несколько) другого "прыгаю" (или ищу) и смотрю. 

Emacs позволяет одновременно редактировать разные части одного и того же файла в разных окнах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существует free-версия VSCommands - [VSCommands Lite](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf), в которой эта фича (Code Block End Tagger) работает, но с ограничением: в конце блока фигурных скобок подсказка о том, какой конкретно блок кода завершается, показывается, однако она некликабельна ([источник](http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/Features2010#CodeBlockEndTagger)). Это неудобство Вам вполне компенсирует hotkey: **Ctrl + ]**.

Comment: Установил по Вашей ссылке плагин

![http://i.imgur.com/Uef4U.png][1]

Но опция "Code Block End Tagger"  доступна только для про версии и соответственно не работает.

![http://i.imgur.com/9g3S7.png][2]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/VJUWP.png
  [2]: http://i.imgur.com/zNNSp.png

Comment: Значит товарищи разработчики давно не обновляли свою инфо-страничку...


Ещё смог найти по теме [VS10x Editor View Enhancer][1], но без оплаты он будет работать только первые 36 дней. Все почему-то требуют денег за эту фичу.
Но если уж она Вам так необходима, то может стоит подумать о приобретении плагина? Имхо, цены на них не так уж запредельны.

  [1]: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34eee02b-f1f6-433a-b210-62e94c0bcb87

Comment: Да, наверное так и сделаю, а каким способом проще купить? А то я пробовал через Visa Electron от Сбербанка оплачивать покупки в интернете, ох и намучился тогда, потратил уйму времени и нервов - всё без толку.

Comment: А вот каким способом проще купить, не подскажу - самому не доводилось.